# creating generic search function for non-sorted generic array

Tags: c, generics, search, vector

I'm creating my personal generic library with function and data structures in C.

I have a generic vector

```
typedef struct vector
{
  int max;
  int size;
  void **data;
} vector_t;
```

and I created functions for vector:

```
int vector_new( vector_t * v, int vecsize );
int vector_add( vector_t *v , void *elem );
int vector_remove( vector_t * v, void *elem);
void vector_free( vector_t *v );
```

In the implementation of the **remove** function, I add the element if and only if the element is not already present in the array of data.
I created a function *search* (because I don't want to sort the element that I insert) to looking for possible duplicates.

Well, I have doubts about the type of 1st parameter that I have to pass to the function. I want to create the function *search* not only for this use, but general.

In remove() I called it like this: `search(v->data, elem);`,
but how will be the prototype of the function?

```
int search( ??? , void * e );
```

I know the 1st parameter could be an array. But I don't know if a `void*`  or a `void**`  for example.
The important is that this function works not just for the struct and functions I have created.

Comment: Why are the return types all int? It seems logical for vector_new() to return a pointer to vector_t, and for vector_seach to return a void * (or NULL). The {add,remove} functions could return an error-code or result-code.

Comment: I return 0 if everything is going well, and -1 if there are errors.

In the function **search** I return the index of the element find in the array; -1 if there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to define a function pointer for comparing elements in the vector for equality.  This can then be added as a parameter to the search method

```
typedef bool (*vector_equals)(void* pLeft, void* pRight);
int vector_search(vector_t* v, vector_equals callback);
```

Now lets say I had a vector which contained `int` values.  I could define my callback as so

```
bool vector_int_equals(void* left, void* right) {
  int* intLeft = left;
  int* intRight = right;
  return *left == * right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do `int search(void **array, unsigned int size, void *data);`.
This is because you always search in an array of pointers (doesn't matter to what), so an array of `void *` looks right.

You may also want to think what comparison is done. If it's a simple `==` between pointers, it's quite simple. But if you need something else, it may be more complicated.

Comment: What do you want to say with "more complicated"? For example strings of char??

Comment: If comparison can't be done by `==`, but needs `strcmp` in some cases, and something else in others, it's more complicated. JaredPar's answer discusses this.